# Url.Action not working on layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am making simple website and i made a menu and i want do redirect other views when i clicked links which is on menu

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>@Page.Title</title>
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 25%;
            background-color: #555;
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            li a.active {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: #000;
            }

            li a:hover:not(.active) {
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                color: #000
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("KitapGoruntule","Home")">Kitapları Görüntüle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">Kitap Kiralama</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Öğrencileri Görüntüle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Öğrenci Ekle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Kitap Ekle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Kiralanmış Kitap Listesi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Görevli Atama</a></li>
            <li><img src="~/img/tpl_logo.gif" style="height:130px;width:325px;margin-left:5px" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
        @RenderBody()
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my master page. when i add @Url.Action Url does not exist in the current context. when i clickedd on for example "KitapGoruntule" i want to open view in home name is KitapGoruntule

Comment: Is there a matching route in your Route.Config and a matching Action in the Controller?

Comment: Check what @AlanBuchanan said and consider using `@Html.ActionLink`.

Comment: @AlanBuchanan how can i understand matching i am newbie on mvc can u explain to me more

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: yeah when i use url.action  Url.Action Url does not exist in the current context. when i use html.Action CS1061: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). and i need to use <a> tag because css files

Answer (score 2):

Using an `ActionLink` will create the `<a>` tag for you.
In your case:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Kitapları Görüntüle", "KitapGoruntule", "Home")
```

Creates:

```
<a href="/Home/KitapGoruntule">Kitapları Görüntüle</a>
```

Comment: i added your code and that line looks             
        ` <li>@Html.ActionLink("Kitapları Görüntüle", "KitapGoruntule", "Home")</li> ` but it says that error 
CS1061: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

It should work, it looks like reference to System.Web.Mvc is missing, please confirm the reference of that DLL in your project.

EDIT:
Also confirm the the below tag in your MAIN web.config:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: i didnt understand what did you mean i am newbie on mvc can u explain more ?

Comment: 1) Open / expand your reference section of mvc project in Visual studio. Look for System.Web.Mvc. If it is there check 2). 2) Open ur web config find webpages:Version in your web config and let me know it is available or not. If not add as above

Comment: it is there in reference section

Comment: then check your web.config

Comment: @FahriBilici Hope you have checked your config file

Comment: <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />

Comment: but i found 2 web.config file one of in the main folder and other in the view folder

Comment: Yes and both should have the same version of System.Web.WebPages, if still no joy, try a following: 1) Go to solution 2) right click and select Manage nuget packages 2) Uninstall MVC version and re-install it 3) Rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link button like this

```
<a href="/Home/KitapGoruntule">Kitapları Görüntüle</a>
```

Comment: yeah it working thanks but i need to understand why actionlink or url.action not working